# Calling LineString.closestPoint or LineString.project methods from Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to use the GEOS library from Python, specifically via [Django](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geos/) (`django.contrib.gis.geos`).

Looking at the GEOS documentation, there are two methods on `LineString` I want to call that aren't available from Python: [`project`](http://geos.osgeo.org/doxygen/classgeos_1_1geom_1_1LineSegment.html#d4468ac21831e174364a8b9b022b4057) and [`closestPoint`](http://geos.osgeo.org/doxygen/classgeos_1_1geom_1_1LineSegment.html#32476249bd06932a852b00e335757a5d).

Is there any reason why they're not available? Can they be added to the Python bindings?

As far as I can tell, they're in `/usr/lib/libgeos_c.so.1.6.0`, is there a way to call them directly if they can't be added to the library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks of it, these methods are part of `LineSegment`, not `LineString` which isn't directly available in the GEOS bindings as is. Geodjango uses ctypes to interface with GEOS, the prototypes can be pulled from
http://code.djangoproject.com/svn/django/trunk/django/contrib/gis/geos/prototypes.

You should be able to extend the code to support them there, but it may be non-trivial as its not an existing geometry type.

Comment: You're right, I didn't pick up on that. Guess LineString and LineSegment were similar enough when I was scanning through for me to not notice. Thanks.